# How to have a CakePHP model field requirement checked manually?

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

**QUESTION UPDATED**: I found out more information and therefor changed my question.

I want to save my user with his license number, but only if he selects that he has a license. I have three possible values for the `pilot_type` field (ROC, ROC-light and recreative) and only the last option should allow for an empty string to be submitted.

In order to achieve this, I wrote the following validation function:

```php
$validator
    ->add('license_nr', 'present_if_license', [
        'rule' => function ($value, $context) {
            return $context['data']['pilot_type'] == 'recreative' || !empty($value);
        },
        'message' => "If you don't fly recreatively, a license number needs to be supplied"
]);
```

The problem is that setting any validation rule on a field will trigger an additional check in the CakePHP Model class that will reject the value if it's empty. I tried to fix this by adding `->allowEmpty('license_nr')`, but that rule makes for the model to accept an empty string without even running my custom function. Even putting them in order and using `'last' => true` on my custom rule doesn't resolve this problem:

```php
$validator
    ->add('license_nr', 'present_if_license', [
        'rule' => function ($value, $context) {
            return false;
            // return $context['data']['pilot_type'] == 'recreative' || !empty($value);
        },
        'last' => true,
        'message' => "If you don't fly recreatively, a license number needs to be supplied"
    ])
    ->allowEmpty('license_nr');
```

How do I make CakePHP run my custom function in order to see if the field can be empty, rather than just assuming that it can never be empty or must always be empty?

Comment: `requirePresence()` won't trigger an error when no _value_ is supplied, it will trigger an error when no _key_ with the given name is supplied. So maybe neither or the rules is actually invoked. Start investigating whether you're actually working on the expected model/table instance (`debug(get_class($modelObject))`).

Comment: You're right, but I just miswrote and meant that it triggers when no key is supplied. Other fields of this model do generate errors aswell by the way, so I must be dealing with the right model.

Comment: Whats the value of `license_nr` when trying to save?

Comment: It's probably a silly question, but the code you wrote here is not valid with the single quote in `don't`. But I guess it's just a mistake in your question ?

Comment: I played around some more and discovered that allowEmpty() will run as the first function and always accepts empty values (like an empty string) without running any other of the validation functions for that field. On the other hand, removing allowEmpty() will always require the value to not be empty. See my updated question above.

Comment: @nIcO The original message wasn't in English, but I changed it to double quotes for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default fields aren't allowed to be empty, so that's the expected behavior and you'll have to explicitly allow empty values.

In order to achieve what you're trying to do, instead of using an additional rule, you should customize the `allowEmpty()` rule, use the second argument to supply a callback (note that unlike rule callbacks it will receive a single argument that provides the context).

So you'd do something like this, which you may need to modify a bit, for example depending on whether you need it to work differently for creating (`$context['newRecord'] = true`) and updating (`$context['newRecord'] = false`) records:

```php
->allowEmpty(
    'license_nr',
    function ($context) {
        return $context['data']['pilot_type'] === 'recreative';
    },
    "If you don't fly recreatively, a license number needs to be supplied"
)
```

As of CakePHP 3.7 you can use `allowEmptyString()`, it will work the same way, you just need to swap the second and third arguments, as `allowEmptyString()` takes the message as the second argument, and the callback as the third argument.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Validation > Conditional Validation](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#conditional-validation)**

Comment: Thanks, your solution works with one caveat: when generating the form using `$this->Form->control`, the required attribute is still set and browser validation will kick in. I can override this ofcourse by explicitly setting `$options['required'] = false`, but I wonder if there isn't a solution where Cake automatically applies this to all instances, rather than me having to do it everywhere manually.

Comment: @AxelKöhler That's a problem with how CakePHP determines that value, it will simply run the rule with no data provided. If applicable you could for example add a check in the callback for when the data is all empty, and return `true` in that case.